# Find a string in one file and replace it with its match in another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Let's say I have two large files. The first one is looking like this:
File1:

```
 N      4764 
    56.067000   50.667000   24.026000
 HT1    4765 
    55.129000   51.012000   24.198000
 HT2    4766 
    56.059000   50.183000   23.126000
```

and the second one:
File2:

```
N    NH2     -0.850000
HT1  H        0.222000
HT2  H        0.222000
```

I would like to replace all the N, HT1, and ..., in the first file with  their matches in the second file (in second column of file2). so the outcome would be:

Outcome:

```
 NH2    4764 
    56.067000   50.667000   24.026000
 H      4765 
    55.129000   51.012000   24.198000
 H      4766 
    56.059000   50.183000   23.126000
```

I am trying to do it with 'sed' but have not worked yet. Maybe awk is a better option?

*edit: My initial examples looked confusing so I changed my examples to the actual files I am dealing with. These are just three lines of my files.

Comment: Do you care about retaining the white space in the output or would it be OK to convert all sequences of white space on each line to single blank chars? Are the fields in your input files separated by chains of blanks or by tabs or by something else?

Comment: if there's no matching replacement string in `File2` then what ... leave the entry in `File1` as is? remove the pair of lines from `File1`? something else?

Comment: if you need to maintain original spacing ... can you confirm that the lines of interest in `File1` have a leading space?

Comment: As long as there is a blank space it is OK, so your solution works for me. Thanks @markp-fuso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2; next }      # 1st file: save entries in array
$1 in a { $1=a[$1] }            # 2nd file: if $1 is an index in array then replace $1 with match from array
1                               # print current line
' File2 File1
```

This generates:

```
NH2 4764
    56.067000   50.667000   24.026000
H 4765
    55.129000   51.012000   24.198000
H 4766
    56.059000   50.183000   23.126000
```

**NOTE:** assumes spacing does not need to be maintained in the lines undergoing a replacement

Answer (score 2):

If the first field of both files are sorted then a simple `join` command will give you the expected result:

```bash
join -o 2.2,1.2,1.3 file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
A3 125 111
B1 132 195
C56 145 695
D3 177 1001
```

If not, then you can use `awk`:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == NR { arr[$1] = $2 OFS $3; next }
    $1 in arr { print $2,arr[$1] }
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: My files are not sorted in separate columns so cannot use the awk you suggested

Comment: @jose the `awk` script doesn't care about the order of the lines, it's `join` that cares about that.

Comment: @EdMorton OP edited his question; the input is completely different (and incompatible) now